# Math.random(rand) doesn't Run

Tags: java

The below code has an error and can't run because of the 'rand' variable. I wonder why?

```
return Math.random(rand);
```

The full code as follows:

```
public class MyProgram
{
    public void start() 
    {
        int num1 = getRandom(7);
        int num2 = getRandom(5);

        System.out.println("The random numbers are : " + num1 + ", " + num2);
    }

    private int getRandom(int rand)
    {
        return Math.random(rand);
    }

}
```

MyApplication:

```
public class MyApplication
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        MyProgram p = new MyProgram();
        p.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by this line? int num1 = getRandom(7); what you wanna achieve  ?

Comment: Remember to [Google for info](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+math+random) and [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()). Doing that would have solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random()` method doesn't take any arguments.
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.random()` doesn't take any parameters in its argument list.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)  You're attempting to pass it *something*, and it doesn't deal with that something.

If you want to start a random number generator with some seed, or generate a new number between 0 and some ceiling, look into [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) instead:

```
Random random = new Random();
// generates a uniformly distributed integer between 0 and rand, exclusive
random.nextInt(rand);
```

Comment: what he means by this line? int num1 = getRandom(7); does he try to generate a random number between 0 and 7?

Comment: He's defined that method within the scope.  Just look a few lines below where it's used.  What its actual *intent* is, I haven't a clue.

Comment: ya i see it, but it does not make sense to me. just try to learn what he wants to achieve?

Comment: +1 for randome.nextInt(rand)

Comment: I'm trying to generate random numbers for each num1 (7) and num2 (5), but don't know how to solve it?

Comment: @user3806881 - What do you mean by "generate a random number for a num"?  This is not a *meaningful* description of what you are trying to do.  Explain yourself properly.